# An error when Customize a caffe loss layer

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, pycaffe

I have encountered an error when training model with my own loss function.

What I want to implement is:

[image: loss function]

My implementation is:

1. train.prototxt

   ```
   layer {
     name: 'similarity_loss'
     type: 'Python'
     bottom: 'fc7'
     bottom: 'labels'
     propagate_down: 1
     propagate_down: 0
     top: 'loss_similarity'
     loss_weight: 1
     python_param {
       module: 'roi_similarity_measure.roi_similarity_loss_layer'
       layer: 'RoISimilarityLossLayer'
     }
   }
   ```
2. loss layer

   ```
   import caffe
   import numpy as np
   class RoISimilarityLossLayer(caffe.Layer):
       def setup(self, bottom, top):
           # check input pair
           if len(bottom) != 2:
               raise Exception("Need two inputs to compute distance - fc7 and labels.")
           # set textual probability matrix for 20 classes
           self._num_classes = 20 + 1
           self._num_rois = (bottom[1].data.shape)[0]
           self._probs = np.ndarray(shape=(self._num_classes, self._num_classes), dtype=float, order='C')
       def reshape(self, bottom, top):
           pass
       def forward(self, bottom, top):
           self._similarity = np.zeros((128, 128), dtype=np.float)
           labels = bottom[1].data.astype(np.int)
           for i in xrange(self._num_rois):
               for j in xrange(self._num_rois):
                   self._similarity[i][j] = self._probs[labels[i]][labels[j]]
           fc7 = bottom[0].data
           fc7_euclidean = 0
           for i in xrange(self._num_rois):
               for j in xrange(self._num_rois):
                   fc7_euclidean += ((fc7[i] - fc7[j]) ** 2) * self._similarity[i][j]
           top[0].data[...] = fc7_euclidean
           top[0].diff[...] = np.zeros((128, 4096), dtype=np.float)
       def backward(self, top, propagate_down, bottom):
           for num in xrange(len(propagate_down)):
               if not propagate_down[num]:
                   continue
               D = np.zeros((128, 128), dtype=np.float)
               for i in xrange(self._num_rois):
                   D[i][i] = self._similarity[i].sum()
                   L = D - self._similarity
               # diff in this layer is calculated by : 2 * (L + transpose L)*fc7
               top[0].diff[...] = 2*(L+L.transpose()).dot(bottom[0].data)
   ```
3. error

> ```
> I0320 09:01:25.520689 22184 layer_factory.hpp:77] Creating layer similarity_loss
> I0320 09:01:25.521440 22184 net.cpp:84] Creating Layer similarity_loss
> I0320 09:01:25.521452 22184 net.cpp:406] similarity_loss <- fc7_drop7_0_split_2
> I0320 09:01:25.521471 22184 net.cpp:406] similarity_loss <- labels_roi-data_1_split_1
> I0320 09:01:25.521478 22184 net.cpp:380] similarity_loss -> loss_similarity
> F0320 09:01:25.521548 22184 blob.cpp:145] Check failed: diff_ 
> *** Check failure stack trace: ***
> ./experiments/scripts/faster_rcnn_end2end.sh: line 57: 22184 Aborted (core dumped) ./tools/train_net.py --gpu ${GPU_ID} --solver models/${PT_DIR}/${NET}/faster_rcnn_end2end/solver.prototxt --weights data/imagenet_models/${NET}.v2.caffemodel --imdb ${TRAIN_IMDB} --iters ${ITERS} --cfg experiments/cfgs/faster_rcnn_end2end.yml ${EXTRA_ARGS}
> ```

I am new to caffe, it's confusing to me. Thank you for your help.

Comment: please do not post code/log as an image. copy-paste your code and format it properly in the question. We need to see more of the log to spot where the error occurred.

Comment: why don't you set and reshape top of your loss layer?

Comment: oh, yes, finally it runs. But it seems my feedforward is wrong. I an confusing about the blob shape in caffe. When the network is setup, it seems the shape of 'fc7' is 1*4096, but when the network is training, when data is input, it seems the shape of 'fc7' is 128*4096 [batch_size, number of neurons]. Thus I am wondering what is the real shape I can get in 'forward' and 'backward'?

Comment: you should make `forward` and `backward` work for any `batch_size`.

Comment: See [PR #5157](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/pull/5157) for a gradient utility check for python layers.

Comment: hi, thank you for your answering. But I am still confused about 'top[0].reshape(...)'. When I reshape 'top[0]', it seems both of 'top[0].data' and 'top[0].diff' have the same shape. But in my loss function, 'top[0].data' is the loss value, which should be a float number, 'top[0].diff' is the gradients of the input data (shape of bottom[0].data is 128*4096), which should be a 128*4096 matrix. You can see the shapes of data and diff are different. Maybe I misunderstood something in caffe's gradient calculation.

Comment: data and diff of blob always have the same shape. you are confusing top.data and bottom.diff. the bottom gradients w.r.t top are stored in bottom.diff and not in top.diff. thus shapes are okay

Comment: Thank you so so so much! It works! You helped me a lot!!!